# angular typescript - typing EventEmitters

Tags: angular, typescript, types, eventemitter

I want my EventEmitter to be typed to a set of classes

```
export const EVENT_ACTIONS = {
    OPEN_EVENT: "OPEN_EVENT",
    OPEN_REGISTRATION: "OPEN_REGISTRATION"
}


export class OpenEventAction { type = EVENT_ACTIONS.OPEN_EVENT; constructor(public payload: SbEvent) { } }
export class OpenRegistrationAction { type = EVENT_ACTIONS.OPEN_REGISTRATION; constructor(public payload: SbEvent) { } }

export type EventActions
    = OpenEventAction
    | OpenRegistrationAction
```

In Component

```
@Output() eventOutput:EventEmitter<EventActions> = new EventEmitter();
```

I'm getting a Decorators are not valid here error
and my IDE says Type EventEmitter ist not generic.

I don't really understand this error. Please help!

Cheers

Comment: You probably didn't import the right EventEmitter class. Post a *complete* minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: that was it...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the incorrect import as mentioned by @JB Nizet in the comments. I was importing `EventEmitter` from `events`. Instead the import needed to be `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'`.

Then I was able to specify a type like so:

```js
@Output('search-term') searchTerm: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```